# Как отформатировать число jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сумма 114358. Эту цифру получаю так: 100 000 * 1.14358.

В итоге мне нужно получить вот такой формат: 1 143.58

Нашел вот эту функцию:

```
function format(n, sep, decimals) {
    sep = sep || "."; // Default to period as decimal separator
    decimals = decimals || 2; // Default to 2 decimals
    return n.toLocaleString().split(sep)[0] + sep + n.toFixed(decimals).split(sep)[1];
}
```

С ее помощью получаю вот такой формат: 114 358.00, но это не то.
Пожалуйста, подскажите как отредактировать эту функцию, или предложите решение,  которым вы пользуетесь, чтобы получить в итоге вот такой формат: 1 143.58

Comment: поделите на 100 перед использованием

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло :)